# Is there a conflict between GuzzleHttp and Laravel Sanctum?

Tags: laravel, guzzle, laravel-sanctum, laravel-9

I have two laravel projects. The first one is an API which works perfectly. This is my login method:

```
/**
 * Login api
 *
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function login( LoginRequest $request ) : JsonResponse
{
    $remember = $request->has( 'remember' );

    if( Auth::attempt( [
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ], $remember )
    ){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->tokens()->delete();
        $success = [
            'token' => $user->createToken( config( 'app.name' ) )->plainTextToken,
            'user' => new UserResource( $user ),
        ];

        return $this->sendResponse( $success, __( 'users.auth.login-succesful' ) );
    }
    else{
        return $this->sendError( __( 'users.auth.login-failed' ), [], 401 );
    }
}
```

When I use postman to verify, everything is peachy, I send this POST request to the login page:

```json
    {
        "username" : "someones_username",
        "password" : "**secure_pass123",
        "remember" : true
    }
```

And I get this response from the API (which is the expected one):

```json
    {
        "success": true,
        "data": {
            "token": "1|FH2T3Hrv1zEWu4nVDFx6jCjTV5oY2yJUQfNKgexT",
            "user": {
                "username": "someones_username",
                "person": {
                    "name": "User",
                    "last": "Lastname",
                    "slug": "user-lastname",
                    "document_number": "00000000",
                    "document_type": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "slug": "id-card",
                        "short": "ic",
                        "name": "Identification Card",
                    }
                },
                "permissions": []
            }
        },
        "message": "users.auth.login-succesful"
    }
```

Now, when I request the Login URL from my Admin project, I get a 500 error message. But it is really weird, because the error starts with this:

```
[2022-03-16 05:29:53] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.deleted_at' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.deleted_at' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1) at C:\\webdev\\projects\\api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:716)
```

Of course the column exists. I tried dumping the LoginRequest $request and it has all the data. So I don't really know what is going on. The .env is correct, it is referencing the correct database.

I am using **Laravel Sanctum** in my API and **GuzzleHttp** in my Admin.

I have activated the SoftDeletes trait in my Model,but the deleted_at column does exist in my migrations. Here is the up method in my CreateUsersTable:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create( 'users', function( Blueprint $table ){
        $table->id();
        $table->string( 'username' )->unique();
        $table->string( 'password' );
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->json( 'data' )->nullable();

        $table->foreignId( 'person_id' )->constrained( 'people' );

        $table->timestamp( 'email_verified_at' )->nullable();
        $table->timestamp( 'deactivated_at' )->nullable();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamp( 'created_at' )->useCurrent();
        $table->timestamp( 'updated_at' )->useCurrent()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
    } );
}
```

And my User class goes like this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Activable, HasData, HasApiTokens, HasFactory, HasRoles, Notifiable, SoftDeletes;
    ...
    ...
}
```

The LoginController in my Admin:

```
    /**
     * Tries to login the user
     *
     */
    public function login( Request $request )
    {
        $params = request( [ 'username', 'password', 'remember', ] );
        return $this->requestURL( 'login', 'POST', $params, [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ] );
    }

    public function requestURL(
        string $url, string $method = 'POST', array $params = [], array $headers = []
    )
    {
        $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
        $url = config( 'superveci.api' ) . '/' . $url;
        $headers = $this->makeHeaders( $headers );
        return $client->request( $method, $url, [
            'json'    => $params,
            'headers' => $headers,
            'verify'  => false,
        ] )->getBody();

    }
```

Comment: The error is very specific, your users table doesn't have a deleted_at as expected, we can't really help you much more when you are certain it is correct. Best advice would be to check it again, check the connection, is it the right one? Check the database, is the column there?

Comment: It's seems like you are using `softDelete` trait while without updating your user table

Comment: It is true, I am using the SoftDeletes trait, but the column is actually there. I added the migration code and also I added the LoginController (login method) to explain how I'm trying to login the user for @NicklasKevinFrank